# CRS conversion of a point from Pulkovo 1952 (58) Stereo70 (ESPG 3844) TO: WGS84 (ESPG: 4326)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84

I have a shapefile loaded from delimited text with exact Northings and Eastings in the Romanian CRS ([ESPG:3844](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3844)). The layer CRS is correctly defined.

Meanwhile, my project CRS is WGS84 (ESPG 4329). OTF is enabled. The point plots on the wrong side of the road.

When I click on info for the layer and check derived location. The error is in the order of 10 or 15 meters.

If I do the conversion on the ESPG website I get the correct location (I know where the physical point is on the earth) and it matches. https://epsg.io/3844

What am I doing wrong? Why does the ESPG website give a different answer to QGIS? How can I get it to agree with the ESPG result and therefore plot correctly? I can't share the coordinates

QGIS version: 2.18.9

Comment: You need to handle the datum transformation choice in QGIS: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#default-datum-transformations

Comment: The official EPSG website is https://www.epsg-registry.org/ it isn't (despite its name) http://epsg.io

Answer (score 4):

On the page you gave reference to we can the following definition of EPSG:3844 in WKT

```
PROJCS["Pulkovo 1942(58) / Stereo70",
    GEOGCS["Pulkovo 1942(58)",
        DATUM["Pulkovo_1942_58",
            SPHEROID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.3,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7024"]],
            TOWGS84[33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6179"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4179"]],
    PROJECTION["Oblique_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",46],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",25],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.99975],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",500000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3844"]]
```

Pay attention to the string TOWGS84[33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84]
This is those 7 coefficients of Helmert transformation used to define Pulkovo_1942_58 datum.
In QGIS the same EPSG:3844 is defined in proj4 as follows

```
+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=2.329,-147.042,-92.08,0.309,-0.325,-0.497,5.69 +units=m +no_defs
```

As you can see in QGIS another Helmert coefficients are given.
So try to define custom crs in Custom Coordinate Reference System dialog

```
 +proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84 +units=m +no_defs
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I have fixed the coefficients and it works perfectly.