# Georefencing vector from Stereo 70 to WGS 84 avoiding deformations

Tags: wgs84

Is there a chance to Georefence or transorm a vector from CRS Stereo 70 to WGS 84 and avoiding all the deformations?

In example is map of Romania, which goes on 0 coordinates of WGS 84.

[image]

Comment: As the warning says you have no transform from Stereo 70 to EPSG:3857 (not WGS84, 4326), does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312055/crs-conversion-of-a-point-from-pulkovo-1952-58-stereo70-espg-3844-to-wgs84 help